# How to check if cell name exists in activesheet using vb.net

Tags: excel

Is it possible to check if a cell name exists (assigned) in the ActiveSheet or not.  I tried using XlApp.ActiveSheet.Cells.Name = "bla" . Any help would be appreciated... Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are referring to named ranges?
Let's say you wish to check if there is any named range called "Bla":

```
for (int i = 1; i <= ActiveWorksheet.Names.Count; i++) {
   Excel.Name name = ActiveWorksheet.Names.Item(i);
   if (name.Name == ActiveWorksheet.Name +  "!Bla") {
      // found the named range
   }
}
```

You can also try to access the named range directly, but this will cause an exception if the named range is not present:

```
var namedRange = ActiveWorksheet.Names.Item("Bla");
```

Please note, that the name of the  named range contains the name of the activeworksheet as well, for example "Sheet1!Bla".

You can do this similarly if the names is saved as a workbook named range.

Comment: Actually I have a list of strings and need to check whether each string is set as cell name within the activesheet or not.  Dont know why ActiveWorksheet.Names.Count is returning 0.. digging into it...

Comment: What do you mean by Cell name? Do you select one cell and enter a name in the "Name Box"? If that is so then you need to check the workbook names, since it save it to a workbook name. Go under Formulas -> Name Manager and check if your Cell names are there and where they are saved.

Comment: you are right Mitja, all the cell names are there. their scope is Workbook and the Refersto property contains the sheetname..